# By how much the mean and variance in size of beans changes after sampling with replacement?

Tags: probability, distributions

You have a bag of $n$ beans of different sizes. The mean and standard deviation of the size of these beans is $\mu_1$ and $\sigma_1$ respectively. The probability of drawing a bean is an increasing function of the size of the bean. More specifically, the probability to draw a bean of size $x$ at a any given draw is

$$P(X=x)=\frac{x}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$$

You draw $n$ beans with replacement from this bag and then measure the mean $\mu_2$ and the standard deviation $\sigma_2$ of the distribution of bean size of these $n$ draws.

**Knowing $\mu_1$ and $\sigma_1$, what are the distributions for $\mu_2$ and $\sigma_2$?**

I don't realize whether one needs to know the whole distribution of bean size to answer this question. If yes, I would love to consider that bean size is normally distributed.

---

**EDIT**

Following @rightskewed comments:

Is the distribution of means after the sampling process is the sampling distribution of the distribution $f_2(X=x) = f_1(X=x) \cdot \frac{x}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$? Given that $n$ is large enough, it means that the distribution of mean after sampling is a normal distribution with mean $\mu_2 = \int f_1(X=x) \cdot \frac{x}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$ and standard deviation $\sigma_2 = \frac{\int f_2(X=x)\cdot(x-\mu_2)^2}{\sqrt{n}}$? The distribution of standard deviations would have some kind of chi-square distribution.

Comment: My simple intuitions: $\mu_2$ is expected to be higher than $\mu_1$ and the difference $\mu_2 - \mu_1$ is expected to be big as $\sigma_1$ is big. Also, $\sigma_2$ is expected to be big if $\sigma_1$ is big and/or if $\mu_2 ≈ \mu_1$.

Comment: $u_2$ = E[X]? and $\sigma_2=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$?

Comment: @rightskewed $u_2 = E[X]$ and $\sigma^2_2 = E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$, where $X$ is the distribution of bean size after sampling $n$ times with replacement. Does it make sense?

Comment: Sampling with replacement is as good as sampling from the original distribution, right?

Comment: $\mu_2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ are the first two moments of the distribution of a bean size after sampling with replacement from the original distribution which is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. Did it answer your question? Thank you!

Comment: $\mu_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n x_i}{n}$ $\sigma_1^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=0}^n (x_i-\mu_1)^2}{n-1}$ And $\mu_2 = E[X] = \sum_{i=0}^n x_iP(X=x_i)$

Comment: Because, $n≠\infty$, $\mu_2$ can take different values. What is the distribution of $\mu_2$?

Comment: $n \rightarrow \infty$  is not a requirement expectation calculation. How would you calculate the expectation of a dice roll for example?

Comment: I am a bit confused... I am trying to calculate the distribution of means (and SDs) that we get after the sampling process. Please see edit in the post. Maybe I got the point.